# What does "4 more to go.." under a comment mean?

Tags: support, comments

I'm trying to enter a comment on SO, and when I hit Add Comment it just prints "4 more to go.." in grey underneath the comment box.  Does this mean I don't have enough reputation to enter a comment?  I did yesterday.  Plus, it's my own question!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must enter at least 15 characters, otherwise it won't let you comment.

When you first click on 'add comment' the text below the comment box displays:

> enter at least 15 characters

The:

> 4 more to go...

means that you must enter 4 more characters.

Comment: To add, before it converts to "X more to go..." it says "enter at least 15 characters" in the same spot, and converts to "X characters left" when you surpass 15. Hm, it may be wise for the message to be updated to say "characters" like the post-limit message does.

Comment: LOL I tried to check, but it said "You can accept an answer in 6 minutes" - using the standards of the character limit, it should just say "6 minutes".

Comment: @orb, haha.  Yeah.  It could be way more clear.  There is plenty of space there too.  Oh well.  Thanks.

Comment: That is confusing UX...

Answer (score 3):

There's a fifteen-character minimum for comments. You only entered eleven.

Comment: Ah - it would be nice if it said "4 more characters to go.." then.  Thanks, I'm going to give the checkmark to the guy who's begging, hope you don't mind.

Comment: @orb, I'm glad my lack of pride can be rewarded sometimes.

Comment: @orbfish I think it assumes you saw the starting message, which is "enter at least 15 characters", but I imagine people rarely notice it

Comment: But what if the comment only goes to 11?

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, there is a minimum 15 character length for comments.

Also, you don't yet have enough reputation on SO to comment on all posts. However, quoting from the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq), "you can always comment on your questions and answers, and any answers to questions you've asked, even with 1 rep."

Comment: Note that on *Meta*, you can comment on *any* post, even with 1 rep.

Comment: You crazy kids with your "meta" sites, I bet you all think you're "cool" and whatnot....