# "X more to go..." under the comment could be more descriptive

Tags: feature-request, support, comments

I got stuck several times with the message

```
X more to go...                   (1a)
```

under the comment that I was posting (X = a number, e.g. 4). I thought that there were X other pending comments in some queue and that I should wait. Since the waiting did not help, I tried to press the "Add Comment" button again, to refresh the page, etc. but without success. Finally I found out that the message means

```
X characters more to enter...      (1b)
```

Of course, I should have known, because there is a message

```
enter at least 15 characters       (0)
```

before the comment field is open, and there is another message

```
Y characters left                  (2)
```

after typing X >= 15 characters. However, while the messages `(0)` and `(2)` are completely clear, the message `(1a)` is rather misleading as also [questions of other users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55603/what-does-4-more-to-go-under-a-comment-mean) show. Wouldn't it be helpful to change the message to something like `(1b)` or even leave `(0)` until the 15 characters are entered?

Comment: @Arjan Probably so. Jiri, can you suggest an alternative?

Comment: I added the tag 'feature-request'. Thanks!