# What is the meaning of "12 more to go..." below Add Comment?

Tags: support, comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does “4 more to go..” under a comment mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55603/what-does-4-more-to-go-under-a-comment-mean)

Sometimes when I try to enter a comment in Stack Overflow my comments are not accepted and a message like this `12 more to go...` appears below Add Comment.

What is the meaning of `12 more to go...` and why does it appear?

Comment: It's counting down to the minimum number of characters in a comment.

Comment: Downvoters should I delete this question, is it not relevant, the please leave a comment. I will delete the question.

Comment: See the [meta-faq#vote-differences]; votes on MSO are different from the regular Stack Exchange websites.

Comment: And you cannot delete a question with up-voted answers, I'm afraid.

Comment: I can always flag it for moderator attention anyway thanks all for answer.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I don't think the voting differences thingy applies here, what's there to disagree with? The downvotes are purely of the no research effort / not useful flavour imho.

Comment: @YannisRizos: Perhaps in this case, I may have knee-jerked an auto-comment. :-P Indeed, `no research` votes all round in this case.

Comment: @codingcrow, no need to delete. This is a legitimate question about what something means.   It's posted in the right place (Meta), and actually addresses a good point:  The clear message,  "enter at least 15 characters" changes to a less clear "x more to go..." one, which is confusing if you didn't happen to see the first message. +1

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Comments must be a minimum of 15 characters in length. You are being prompted to add another 12 to whatever you've already typed.

[image: Empty comment box]

...becomes...

[image]

Comment: Is this in the FAQ anywhere?

Comment: I would not have thought it necessary. It's fairly self-explanatory.

Comment: @luke this is more like a RAQ or ANAQ. Rarely or almost never asked.

Comment: Maybe there should be a RAQ section of the FAQ....(joking).

Answer (score 6):

There is a minimal length of comments. `...more to go` indicates the characters left to have the minimum length.

Answer (score 5):

That is the minimum number of characters that should be in a comment. Refer [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) to learn more about commenting.